# Why sendFile method to display the source code instead of html page

Tags: node.js, express

I encountered a new problem in the nodejs.
The following code is a demo of the **express framework**. 
I want to return a html page, but returned to the page's source code. 
Why browser does not parse pages? Please help me!

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: this code is working fine when I run it.

Comment: @John Yeah , It is sometimes normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this

```
app.use(express.static('../views'));
```

instead of

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/index.html'));
});
```

extra edit: you can make this index.html static , then you can edit it via Angular etc. this would be a better solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late.Thank you for your suggestion, I will use it. This is the correct way to use. It's very good. Thanks for you again!